# What airplane model was this historic propeller attached to?

Tags: aviation-history, propeller

I have a 9-foot historic wooden biplane propeller with brass edges. It does have a serial number, but it is tough to read. 2250 DN 152 6' 6" is what it appears to say. I am attaching a photo of it. Does anyone know what model it may have come from / how to find out which one?

[image]

Comment: Can you take a picture of the serial number? Provide exact measurements of the blades?

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and guess that the propeller is 6 feet, 6 inches long.